# Call remote bash function via ansible

Tags: linux, bash, ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

Is it possible to call a remote function defined in bash (for example added in one of the scripts that are stored under /etc/profile.d) via ansible ad-hoc command (using shell , command modules ?)

For example I have the following function that allows to see the status of apt history:

```
function apt-history(){
  case "$1" in
    install)
          cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'install '
          ;;
    upgrade|remove)
          cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep $1
          ;;
    rollback)
          cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep upgrade | \
              grep "$2" -A10000000 | \
              grep "$3" -B10000000 | \
              awk '{print $4"="$5}'
          ;;
    *)
          cat /var/log/dpkg.log
          ;;
  esac
}
```

Is it possible to make a call to this function directly via function name from one of the ansible existing modules via ad-hoc command ? I know it would be possible to create a new script and call it directly remotely, but this is not what I want to achieve here. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have to instantiate bash on the remote side, using the command or shell module like this :

```
ansible localhost -m command -a 'bash -lc apt-history'
```

This is a common trick if you need environment variables to be set-up.

Comment: ok great, it worked ! In order to pass arguments to remote function I did used quotation and a bit modified syntax and it works fine (btw command is a default module in ansible so I can skip it). My modified command: **ansible testbed  -a 'bash -lc "apt-history install"'**